# Appending rather than overwriting files when moving

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have the following directory structure:

```
+-archive
  +-a
    +-data.txt
  +-b
    +-data.txt 
+-incoming
  +-a
    +-data.txt
  +-c
    +-data.txt
```

How do I do the equivalent of `mv incoming/* archive/` but have the contents of the files in `incoming` appended to those in `archive` rather than overwrite them?

Comment: Hello, ukas1, welcome to StackOverflow. Nice to see someone using the markdown syntax correctly in his/her first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# move to incoming/ so that we don't
# need to strip a path prefix
cd incoming

# create directories that are missing in archive
for d in `find . -type d`; do
  if [ ! -d "../archive/$d" ]; then
    mkdir -p "../archive/$d"
  fi
done

# concatenate all files to already existing
# ones (or automatically create them)
for f in `find . -type f`; do
  cat "$f" >> "../archive/$f"
done
```

This should find any file in `incoming` and concatenate it to an existing file in `archive`.

The important part is to be *inside* `incoming`, because else we'd had to strip the path prefix (which is possible, but in the above case unnecessary). In the above case, a value of `$f` typically looks like `./a/data.txt`, and hence the redirection goes to `../archive/./a/data.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and the welcome). It does just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with proper quoting:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    # acting as parent script
    find incoming -type f -exec "$0" {} \;
else
    # acting as child script
    for in_file; do
        if [ -f "$in_file" ]; then
            destfile="${in_file/incoming/archive}"
            test -d "$(dirname "$destfile")" || mkdir -p "$_"
            cat "$in_file" >> "$destfile" &&
            rm -f "$in_file"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: The problem is, that `basename` is too little. Inside incoming and archive, there seems to be a significant directory structure.

Comment: @Boldewyn - Acknowledged and fixed. Now it uses Bash's regex replacement.

Comment: You're not setting `in_file` anywhere and it's missing a dollar sign in the for statement.

Comment: @Dennis - It's proper syntax. `for in_file; do` is just shorthand for `for in_file in "$@"; do` which will cycle through all arguments to the script, setting the variable `$in_file` to the current argument. Using a dollar sign in the `for` statement is improper syntax... Perhaps it is time to read up on BASH syntax.

Comment: You're right. I had forgotten about that feature. I just find it more readable to refer to `"$@"` explicitly. Perhaps readability is a valid goal.

Answer (score 0):

run it on the current directory.

```
find ./incoming  -type f | while read -r FILE
do
  dest=${FILE/incoming/archive}
  cat "$FILE" >> "$dest"
done
```

the one in `incoming/c` would not be appended though